# Sql server - select correct "Text" values as new value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

i have a query where I'm selecting information from two different tables - I'm doing an inner join and pulling up text values instead of ID's. What's happening tho is the headers for all these columns are not in text format that I want it to be. In my application I have to change all the headers. Here's my query...

```
SELECT IDClient,t2.Name Dept,t3.Name Position,Salary 
FROM TblClientData t1 
INNER JOIN tblDataRef t2 ON t1.Dept = t2.ID
INNER JOIN tblDataRef t3 ON t1.Position = t3.ID
WHERE  IDClient = 177
```

Basically what I'm looking to do is instead of

```
SELECT IDClient, t2.Name Dept
```

Where t2.Name Dept will have a heading Dept

I want to name it something different, something like

```
SELECT IDClient, t2.Name Dept as [Department]
```

When i do this I get an error....

Comment: what?, just change `Dept` with `Department`

Comment: Yeah so when I select it the header text is different

Comment: I don't think you understood. Literally just change our code `SELECT IDClient, t2.Name Department`

Comment: When you post a question because you are getting an error it would be extremely helpful to those trying to help if you posted the actual error message. That way we don't have to guess what the problem might be. As posted this is very challenging to understand what you are trying to do. Is this t2.Name being aliased as Dept or is the column name "Name Dept"?

Comment: @SeanLange - my apologies - I was trying to alias it as Department

Comment: So then as has been pointed out already this is simple. t2.Name as Department.

Comment: @SeanLange - i understand I was waiting for SO to let me accept the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have both `Dept` and `Department.  You only need one:

```
SELECT IDClient, t2.Name as Department
```

I always use `as` with column aliases.  It makes it easier to spot error like this.

Also, there is no need to escape `Department`.  I find the square braces to be a bit messy when they are not needed.

Comment: I think I'll need them if my header is more than 1 word

Comment: You'll need them if you have any spaces @Bobski, but in general try and use Proper Case or camel case or underscores so you don't have to deal with brackets. i.e.`FirstName` or `First_Name` versus `[First Name]`. It makes your code a lot easier to write.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this with quotes

```
 SELECT IDClient,t2.[Name Dept] AS Department ,t3.[Name Position],Salary
```